# Query MariaDB from NodeJS without Caching from MariaDB

Tags: javascript, database, mariadb, sequelize.js

I try to do a query from MariaDB with my NodeJS without using the MariaDB caching. I use Sequelize to query the database.

Everything works fine but I recognized that there is definitly some issue with caching. The select query I use always reports a long time that a new user is not available. But another MariaDB insert generated the data before.
To check the user I use:

```
    isUserExists: async function ( inUser, inChat, inLevel ) {

        const iskunde = await kunden.findAll({
            where: {
              kunde: inUser,
              chat: inChat,
              level: inLevel,
              created_at: {
                [Op.gte]: Sequelize.literal("DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)"),
              },
            },
            raw: true,
          }); 
          //var currentdate = new Date();
          //console.log(currentdate);
          //console.log(iskunde);
          if(Array.isArray(iskunde) && iskunde.length) {
            return true;
          }else{
            return false;
          }  

    },
```

This becomes a big problem with my app. So I try to find a way to get the "realtime" data from database.  From what I read there is a SELECT possible with SQL_NO_CACHE but I do not find any information how to manage this with Sequelize. Any idea?

Comment: create [indexes](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/indexes/), `fields ['kunde', 'chat', 'level', 'created_at']`. And the response time should be solved. It may not be completely obvious how sequelize.js maps to queries, but [Use the index luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) is a good read on their function.

Comment: I think indexes are not the ground problem. I did it exact like in the description and the queries are still brutal cached. I need to find a way to "force" make a new entry available for all select queries.

Comment: MariaDB doesn't cache query results by default. The non-default query cache won't cache time variant queries that include `NOW()` so `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE` won't help. If there's caching, its at your application layer somehow.